# Highcharts numberFormat returns minus zero

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts and noticed sometimes when the chart has values very close to zero it formats the y axis labels or the tooltip value to "-0.00".

I tried this code:

```
Highcharts.numberFormat(-0.00002,2)
```

and it returns "-0.00". It should be "0.00".

I tried wraping the `numberFormat` function with `Highcharts.wrap` to catch this case but with no success, my wrapper was not executed. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function (H) {
        H.wrap(H, 'numberFormat', function (proceed, number, decimals, decPoint, thousandsSep) {
            var originalResult = proceed.call(number, decimals, decPoint, thousandsSep);
            var result = originalResult.isMinusZero() ? originalResult.cutMinusSign() : originalResult;
            return result;
        });
    }(Highcharts));
});
```

Can anyone find my mistake or maybe offer some other solution?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `Highcharts.numberFormat()`. It is using JavaScript `toFixed()` function. It just shows you on which side of zero is your number. For example: `var num  = -0.00002; num.toFixed(2)` returns "-0.00". Calling it again `num.toFixed(5)` will return your original number: "-0.00002"

Comment: @AntoJurković your comment is not exactly correct. `Highcharts.numberFormat()` is using `toFixed()` but only after calling `abs()` (`mathAbs(n).toFixed(c)`). it checks before if the number is negative (saves a string with the sign: `s = n < 0 ? "-" : ""`).

Comment: You are right. I simplified it a little. But sign is still preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wrap` work fine with methods from prototype, try to overwrite numberFormat in that way:

```
(function (H) {
    var proceed = H.numberFormat;
    H.numberFormat = function (number, decimals, decPoint, thousandsSep) {
        var originalResult = proceed(number, decimals, decPoint, thousandsSep);
        var result = originalResult.isMinusZero() ? originalResult.cutMinusSign() : originalResult;
        return result;
    };
}(Highcharts));

Highcharts.numberFormat(-0.002, 4);
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/765/